# Vercel gives me a error while deploying a Vercel site

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, vercel, docusaurus

Vercel gives me a error while deploying a Vercel site.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/Mrdev88/useimg

Here's the error:

```
[20:14:55.571] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
[20:14:55.697] Cloning github.com/Mrdev88/useimg (Branch: draft/epic-ride, Commit: 68b4e7e)
[20:14:55.709] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[20:14:55.990] Cloning completed: 292.545ms
[20:14:56.239] Running "vercel build"
[20:14:56.674] Vercel CLI 32.4.1
[20:14:57.331] Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=18.0" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is released. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
[20:14:57.334] Installing dependencies...
[20:14:57.680] yarn install v1.22.17
[20:14:57.770] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[20:14:57.773] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[20:14:58.252] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[20:15:11.016] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[20:15:11.019] warning "@docusaurus/core > react-loadable-ssr-addon-v5-slorber@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-loadable@*".
[20:15:11.030] warning "@docusaurus/core > react-dev-utils > fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>= 2.7".
[20:15:11.043] warning " > @mdx-js/react@3.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@>=16".
[20:15:11.044] warning "@docusaurus/preset-classic > @docusaurus/plugin-debug > @microlink/react-json-view > flux@4.0.4" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.0.2 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
[20:15:11.045] warning "@docusaurus/preset-classic > @docusaurus/theme-search-algolia > @docsearch/react > @algolia/autocomplete-preset-algolia@1.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "@algolia/client-search@>= 4.9.1 < 6".
[20:15:11.045] warning "@docusaurus/preset-classic > @docusaurus/theme-search-algolia > @docsearch/react > @algolia/autocomplete-core > @algolia/autocomplete-plugin-algolia-insights@1.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "search-insights@>= 1 < 3".
[20:15:11.046] warning "@docusaurus/preset-classic > @docusaurus/theme-search-algolia > @docsearch/react > @algolia/autocomplete-core > @algolia/autocomplete-shared@1.9.3" has unmet peer dependency "@algolia/client-search@>= 4.9.1 < 6".
[20:15:18.344] [5/5] Building fresh packages...
[20:15:19.095] Done in 21.42s.
[20:15:19.124] Running "yarn run build"
[20:15:19.305] yarn run v1.22.17
[20:15:19.336] $ docusaurus build
[20:15:20.809] 
[20:15:20.811] Error: Docusaurus could not load module at path "/vercel/path0/docusaurus.config.js"
[20:15:20.811] Cause: ParseError: Unterminated string constant.  
[20:15:20.811]  /vercel/path0/docusaurus.config.js:23:20
[20:15:20.811]     at loadFreshModule (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/utils/lib/moduleUtils.js:36:15)
[20:15:20.813]     at loadSiteConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/config.js:35:62)
[20:15:20.813]     at async loadContext (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/index.js:31:63)
[20:15:20.813]     at async Command.build (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js:60:21) {
[20:15:20.813]   [cause]: Error: ParseError: Unterminated string constant.  
[20:15:20.813]    /vercel/path0/docusaurus.config.js:23:20
[20:15:20.813]       at loadFreshModule (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/utils/lib/moduleUtils.js:33:16)
[20:15:20.813]       at loadSiteConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/config.js:35:62)
[20:15:20.813]       at async loadContext (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/index.js:31:63)
[20:15:20.814]       at async Command.build (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js:60:21)
[20:15:20.814] }
[20:15:20.814] 
[20:15:20.814] [INFO] Docusaurus version: 3.0.0
[20:15:20.814] Node version: v18.17.1
[20:15:20.831] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[20:15:20.832] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[20:15:20.849] Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

I added Apostrophes to the code where it didn't have one in docusaurus.config.js and I was expecting for it to work and it didn't

Comment: Here is what I received from checkly: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()